# Increasing the recovery time while postgreSQL startup

Tags: postgresql

How can I increase the recovery time of postgreSQL while starting up after an immediate stop?

I started the postgreSQL normally and tried to insert the huge number of data. while inserting, I stopped the server with immediate stop command. While starting the server again, it moved to the recovery mode and it takes few seconds to startup.

Is there any possibility to move the server to recovery mode for long time (say 10-15 mins)?. If yes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can raise `checkpoint_timeout` and `max_wal_size` and generate a lot of write activity for a long time.